# What do lists of multiple font families mean in VS Code font family setting values?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everywhere it seems to say that I just simply need to change 'editor.fontFamily'. But how? This is the default value for it:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
```

What do all those multiple entries mean ( like monospace with and without quotes ) and how would I change it to 'DejaVu' fonts for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VScode does its styling via CSS. This is knows as a "[fallback group](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_font.asp)". If one font is not available, it automatically uses the next one in line, from left to right.

To do what you asked for:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'DejaVu Mono', 'monospace'"
```

If that doesn't work, look up the correct name of the font and put in in there. The quotes are used mainly with names that have spaces in them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know why there are two monospace but one without single quotes?

Comment: No idea. Probably related to cross-platform issues. If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the multiple entries, from the [CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family):

> Font family names that happen to be the same as a keyword value ('inherit', 'serif', 'sans-serif', 'monospace', 'fantasy', and 'cursive') must be quoted to prevent confusion with the keywords with the same names.

So in other words, `monospace` is a reserved word/font for the `font-family` CSS property, and if you have a font with the same name, you need to quote it. So VS Code's default settings prioritizes the `'monospace'` font before the default `monospace` font.

I hope that makes sense.